# handling of many matrices in fortran program

Tags: matrix, fortran

this is my program

```
program matrix
real :: J1(38,38),J2(38,29),J3(29,38),J4(29,29)
real :: J13(38,1),J23(29,1),J33(1,68),Jac(68,68)
!!all matrices contains some values except Jac

Jac=[J1 J2 J13
     J3 J4 J23
     J33      ]
end program matrix
```

Now i want to put all these matrices into 1 matrix Jac(68,68)
so that Jac=[J1 J2 J13
             J3 J4 J23
             J33      ]
what should be the fortran code..please help me.

Comment: Use 2 DO-loops (nested) to iterate over elements of Jac and index offsets to put each element from J1..J33 into their corresponging place in Jac.

Comment: What are you doing with this? Some kind (guessing from the name J) vibration analysis - stiffener matrix?

Answer (score 10):

Or, if you don't like writing loops you could write;

```
Jac(1:38,1:38) = J1
Jac(1:38,39:38+29) = J2
```

and so forth.

**EDIT**

I can't tell from what you've posted if this bit will be of interest, but I infer a level of Fortran knowledge which does not include this ...

you could define:

```
real, target :: jac(68,68) 
real, dimension(:,:), pointer :: j1, j2, j3, j4, j13, j23, j33
```

and use these sub-arrays like this:

```
j1 => jac(1:38,1:38)
j33 => jac(1,:)
```

*etc*.  This way you have only one copy of the data in memory, which for such small arrays probably doesn't matter.  And it is the wrong approach if the contents of the subarrays and of the super array should be different.

Answer (score 3):

To put it a bit more concise you can also use

```
JAC( 1:38, 1:38) = J1 (1:38,1:38)
JAC( 1:38,39:67) = J2 (1:38,1:29)
JAC( 1:38,   68) = J13(1:38,   1)
JAC(39:67, 1:38) = J3 (1:29,1:38)
JAC(39:67,39:67) = J4 (1:29,1:29)
JAC(39:67,   68) = J23(1:29,   1)
JAC(   68, 1:68) = J33(   1,1:68)
```

If you have bigger arrays, where copying might not be a good idea, I suggest you write a function that converts indices automatically. For fun I added a custom type `MATRIX` containing all the submatrices without specifying it explicitly below. So you have

```
REAL FUNCTION JAC(I,J, JAC_MAT)
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: I,J
  TYPE(MATRIX), INTENT(IN) :: JAC_MAT
  IF(I.LE.38.AND.J.LE.38)THEN
    JAC = JAC_MAT%J1(I,J)
  ELSEIF(I.LE.38.AND.J.LE.67)THEN
    JAC = JAC_MAT%J2(I,J-38)
  ...
  ENDIF
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over Jac and assign elements of `Jx(.,.)` to `Jac(i,j)`. For example, this is how you assign `J1` to `Jac` leftmost upper block:

```
DO i = 1, 38
   DO j = 1, 38
     Jac(i,j) = J1(i,j)
   END DO
 END DO
```